# Copying (Cloning) DB to another Vertica Cluster with Different no. of Nodes and Different IP Addresses

Tags: database, database-migration, vertica, database-cloning

I have this requirement where I have to copy the complete DB from a single node installation to a 2 nodes cluster of Vertica. As per the documentation this is not possible.

**Are there no workaround methods for performing this?**

We may not always have same no. of nodes in different clusters especially when it is a pre-prod and prod case. So some method must exist for doing this.

Kindly advise on the same.

Comment: You can always try export and import data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this not possible at this time.

You can export to another single node, then add a node. As a side note, you want at least 3 nodes for a production environment.

For users, roles and permissions, see [datadug.com](http://datadug.com/how-to-script-out-users-roles-and-permissions-in-vertica/)'s export script.

With regards to moving data, you have a few options:

1. **`EXPORT TO VERTICA`** - Allows for for export of an entire table, specific columns, or the result of a `SELECT`
2. **`COPY FROM VERTICA`** - Works similiar to `EXPORT` however does not allow for the result of a `SELECT`
3. **`vsql`** - Import flat files by piping out an input into the output of another `vsql` command using `COPY`

Comment: Exporting to single node and then extending it seems to be the simpler solution. But I see conflicting information on this. As per the documentation, it is given that a single node installation cannot be extended. (Referred : [Vertica 6.1 Documentation](http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#2017.htm), bullet no. 1 under **"Installation Scenarios"**). 

So is it possible?

Comment: @anshuman That documentation is outdated. The [latest documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/InstallationGuide/Other/InstallationOverviewAndChecklist.htm) clarifies that it only applies to `localhost` processes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems like my problem is solved.
I can migrate to new cluster with single node and then extend the same to two nodes. 

Being new to this forum, is there anyway I can mark this post as "Solved"?

Comment: @anshuman There should be a little green checkbox under by the up/down vote you can use to accept this answer.